# Add Sequence with same id mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on some legacy code/database, and need to add a field to the database which will record a sequence number related to that (foreign) id.

Example product table (current):

```
PRODUCT_ID  some_stuff
1           ...
1           ...
1           ...
2           ...
2           ...
1           ...
```

there is no auto increment for product table.

I need to add a sequenceid column which increments separately for each account, achieving:

```
product_id  SEQ     another_stuff
1           1       ...
1           2       ...
1           3       ...
2           1       ...
2           2       ...
1           4       ...
```

The sequence is related to product_id.

is there a way i can make it works?

Comment: And do you need this? And what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: @b0s3 hi. i've tried INSERT INTO temp_pic ( id, seq )
    SELECT product_id, 
      (SELECT count(*) + 1 FROM product c 
      WHERE c.product_id = product.product_id) as seq 
    FROM product;

but im getting same sequence for same product id

Comment: Not getting any error with the query?

Comment: @b0s3 hi. its no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by adding the column:

```
alter table add column seq int;
```

Then you can do this using variables:

```
set @rn = 0;
set @p = -1;

update products p
    set seq = (@rn := if(@p = product_id, @rn + 1,
                         if(@p := product_id, 1, 1)
                        )
              )
    order by product_id;
```

Note that you have no control over the ordering of the rows, because you don't seem to have a field that says which row should be first.

Comment: works like charm. its new for me using variables. Thanks. will learn more about that.
need 5 minutes before i can accept the answer. :p